# SQL to get Team Records from Games Database

Tags: mysql, sql, database

For one of my sports related project, I need to show the record counts of teams.

Example: "Team 1" and "Team 2" has played 5 games. "Team 1" has won 3 times and "Team 2" has won 2 times. So the output should be (3-2).

Here is the table structure with some data.

```
ID ---- TEAM1 ---- SCORE1 ---- TEAM2 ---- SCORE2
1       70         1           73         2
2       74         0           70         1
3       74         2           73         1
4       73         1           70         0
```

The output should be something like:

```
TEAM1 ---- TEAM2---- RECORD
70         73         2-0
74         70         0-1
74         73         1-0
```

NOTE:

- There will be always a winner and no game can be a draw.
- In the output, the combination of team1 and team2 should be unique.

**[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4dead/1/0)** : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4dead/1/0

Comment: What is your question/what are you struggling with.

Comment: Suggestion: Use a many-to-many relationship instead for Match ID + Team. Having `team1` and `team2` columns in a table is not a good database design and will sooner or later cause problems for you. (For this question alone, it would already be easier with a many-to-many relationship)

Comment: I am not able to get the final cominatin of records. I am able to get which team won in a given game.. but the final result should be the combination of all games.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg: The database is like this and I have literally no control over it now.

Comment: @Purus Then it is something to think about for future projects.

Comment: Thanks. I am currently looking to finish out of my current work now with this design :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tricky thing here is dealing with the same teams playing in home and away fixtures. This can be worked around with (lots of) case statements.

The basic approach is to reformat the data so that the team with the lowest id appears first.

```sql
select 
   least(homeTeam, awayTeam) team1,
   greatest(homeTeam, awayTeam) team2,
   sum(case when awayTeam > homeTeam
       then case when homeTeamScore > awayTeamScore then 1 else 0 end
       else case when homeTeamScore > awayTeamScore then 0 else 1 end
   end) team1Wins,
   sum(case when hometeam > awayteam
       then case when homeTeamScore > awayTeamScore then 1 else 0 end
       else case when homeTeamScore > awayTeamScore then 0 else 1 end
   end) team2Wins
from
  games
group by
   least(homeTeam, awayTeam),
   greatest(homeTeam, awayTeam);
```

**<kbd>[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4dead/12)</kbd>**

or slightly more compact, but possibly harder to understand:

```
select 
   least(homeTeam, awayTeam) team1,
   greatest(homeTeam, awayTeam) team2,
   sum(case sign(awayTeam - homeTeam) 
       when sign(homeTeamScore - awayTeamScore) then 1
       else 0 end) team1Wins,
   sum(case sign(awayTeam - homeTeam) 
       when sign(awayTeamScore - homeTeamScore) then 1
       else 0 end) team2Wins
from
  games
group by
   least(homeTeam, awayTeam),
   greatest(homeTeam, awayTeam);
```

**<kbd>[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4dead/14)</kbd>**

Comment: Looks like you have solved the problem. I will test it with my data and accept this question. Thanks.